# Why do I NOT get a tag 271 size entry in IncrementalRefresh change message

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I have requested IncrementalRefresh in FIX 4.4

After I receive intial Full Refresh, I get a 35=X message with MDUpdateType = 1 (Change).

However, there is NO fix tag 271. I believe I should only get a change message when something has changed OTHER than price (that would be a different or new MDEntry). Which I assumed would be size.

What else could this message be telling me?

Answer (score 0):

MDEntrySize <271> **Conditionally** required when MDUpdateAction <279> = New(0) andMDEntryType <269> = Bid(0), Offer(1), Trade(2) ), Trade Volume(B), or Open Interest(C).

http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/msgType_X_88.html

Hope this helps.